# Unexpected assignment in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a somewhat weird problem which is probably derived from how indexing works in numpy. But for some reason I don't seem to understand it, let alone reach the behavior I'm expecting:

```
>>> a = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U10')
>>> a
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U10')
>>> a[0] = ['e']
>>> a
array([['e', 'e'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U10')
```

So what I was expecting is to obtain

```
array([['e'], ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U10)
```

Can someone give me a hint as of why this is not working as I was expecting, and how to reach the expected behavior?

Also, and in reaction to roganjosh's comment:

```
>>> a = np.array([np.array(['a', 'b']), np.array(['c', 'd'])])
>>> a[0] = 'e'
>>> a
array([['e', 'e'],['c', 'd']], dtype=object)
```

However:

```
>>> a = np.array([np.array(['a', 'b', 'l']), np.array(['c', 'd'])])
>>> a[0] = 'e'
>>> a
array(['c', array(['c', 'd'], dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)
```

which feels sort of weird.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have that expected output because that would be a jagged array. Numpy is extending the dimensions of the single-item list you've given to be an array to keep the same shape you initialised `a` with

Comment: You can test this with `arr = np.array([[1], [2, 3]])` and you'll get `array([list([1]), list([2, 3])], dtype=object)` at which point you really need to be questioning why you're using numpy at all. It's now just a nested list with the overhead of numpy, yet none of the decent parts of numpy will work on an `object` dtype

Comment: You are expecting a list behavior, replacing the first element of a list with another list.  For this array the assignment is actually `a[0,:] = ['e']`, assigning 'e' to all elements of the 0 row.

Comment: Right... actually

```a = np.array([np.array(['a', 'b']), np.array(['c', 'd'])]); a[0] = 'e'```

would return
`array([['e', 'e'],['c', 'd']], dtype=object)`.

However,
```a = np.array([np.array(['a', 'b', 'l']), np.array(['c', 'd'])]); 
a[0] = 'e'```

would return `array(['c', array(['c', 'd'], dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)`

which feels sort of weird.

Comment: I suggest adding that example as an [edit] and not as a comment

Comment: Yes, thanks. Adding this as a comment is being quite of a nightmare.

Comment: Your counter example is flawed because you can see that the array is of type `object` and so broadcasting and other numpy tricks no longer apply. You just have a nested list'

Comment: Sure, but isn't it sort of unexpected that the same operation behaves differently depending on the number of elements within an array? And also, how can I reach the same behavior as with the second case (different number of elements), but with the first case (same number of elements)?

Comment: I can see why you think it's confusing but actually, the underlying cause is that you're misusing the numpy library (I don't mean that in a harsh way). That leads on to the answer for your second point; don't use numpy if that's what you expect to happen. Just use regular lists. Numpy is not an enhanced python list; arrays have specific purposes

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. Actually, using lists does lead to my script delivering the expected results in all test cases (as opposed to using numpy as "enhanced" lists). I still feel there would be use cases where this behavior would lead to potential problems (and using lists would not be a solution), but unless I can think of it, using lists is the solution :) Thanks!

Comment: If you see `object` as the dtype, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. This also applies to Pandas

Answer (score 1):

In your last example, you make a 2 element array.  Each element can be anything - a string, a list, or array:

```
In [113]: a = np.array([np.array(['a', 'b', 'l']), np.array(['c', 'd'])])
<ipython-input-113-3010d1b297e2>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  a = np.array([np.array(['a', 'b', 'l']), np.array(['c', 'd'])])
```

Without the warning:

```
In [114]: a = np.array([np.array(['a', 'b', 'l']), np.array(['c', 'd'])],object)
     ...: 
In [115]: a.shape
Out[115]: (2,)
In [116]: a
Out[116]: 
array([array(['a', 'b', 'l'], dtype='<U1'),
       array(['c', 'd'], dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)
In [117]: a[0]
Out[117]: array(['a', 'b', 'l'], dtype='<U1')
In [118]: a[0] = ['foobar']
In [119]: a
Out[119]: array([list(['foobar']), array(['c', 'd'], dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)
In [120]: a[0] = 'foobar'
In [121]: a
Out[121]: array(['foobar', array(['c', 'd'], dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)
```

This array behaves very much like a 2 element list.  In fact I'd question the value of using such an array instead of a list.

Creating an object dtype array with arrays that are all the same shape can be tricky, because `np.array` tries to makes multidimensional array where possible (as in your original example).

```
In [133]: a = np.empty(2,object)     # 'blank' array with desired shape
In [134]: a
Out[134]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [135]: a[:] = [['a','b'],['c','d']]    # assign 2 lists to it
In [136]: a
Out[136]: array([list(['a', 'b']), list(['c', 'd'])], dtype=object)
In [137]: a[1] = np.array(['a','b'])     # assign an array to an element
In [138]: a
Out[138]: array([list(['a', 'b']), array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)
```

The display gives information about the array elements.

### 2d array

The original example is 2d array.  The fact that it is string dtype (or object) doesn't make much difference.  It could just as well a numeric array.  You can't change the shape by assignment.

```
In [122]: b = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U10')
In [123]: b
Out[123]: 
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U10')
In [124]: b.shape
Out[124]: (2, 2)
```

The regular multidimensional array indexing rules apply, including `broadcasting`.

```
In [125]: b[0]
Out[125]: array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U10')
In [126]: _.shape
Out[126]: (2,)
In [127]: b[0] = 'd'         # broadcast to the whole row
In [128]: b
Out[128]: 
array([['d', 'd'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U10')

In [129]: b[0] = ['d','e']    # assign separate elements to the row
In [130]: b
Out[130]: 
array([['d', 'e'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U10')

In [131]: b[:,1] = ['x','y']   # assign to a column
In [132]: b
Out[132]: 
array([['d', 'x'],
       ['c', 'y']], dtype='<U10')
```

Look at how these arrays are converted to a list:

```
In [139]: a.tolist()
Out[139]: [['a', 'b'], array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')]
In [140]: b.tolist()
Out[140]: [['d', 'x'], ['c', 'y']]
```

`numpy` is optimized for numeric multidimensional arrays.  All the fast compiled code works on numeric values.  It can store strings and general objects, but the processing is at Python speeds, not fast compiled ones.